# Guidance needed with basic python battleship game

Tags: python, pyscripter

I am working on this script of a basic battleships game. I am new to python and would like some guidance to where i am going wrong. I think all the code is there that is needed any help will be much appreciated Thanks!

```
 def main():

   from random import randint

#initializing board

board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["o"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
 for row in board:
  print( " ".join(row))

#starting the game and printing the board

print ("Let's play Battleship!")
print_board(board)

#defining where the ship is
def random_row(board):
  return  randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

#asking the user for a guess

for turn in range(4):
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

    # if the user's right, the game ends
    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print ("Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!")
        break
    else:
        #warning if the guess is out of the board
        if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
            print ("Oops, that's not even in the ocean.")

        #warning if the guess was already made

        elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
            print ("You guessed that one already.")

        #if the guess is wrong, mark the point with an X and start again

        else:
            print ("You missed my battleship!")
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"

        # Print turn and board again here
        print ( "Turn " + str(turn+1) + " out of 4.")
        print_board(board)

#if the user have made 4 tries, it's game over
if turn >= 10:
    print ("Game Over")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? The code you posted is weird, your main() function is only one line and all it does is import randint.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: hi its mainly where im going wrong!

Comment: It pops up with an error saying randint is not defined, whereabouts should i be defining it ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code won't run like this because the indentation is broken. In Python, indentation isn't just good style which makes your program more readable; it's what tells the computer the structure of your program. After fixing the indentation, I tried your program and it worked as expected. The “Game Over” message isn't printed, though, because at the point where it would be printed, the variable `turn` contains the value `3` which was assigned to it last, and not `10`.

Some random thoughts on your code:

- It's good style to put all import statements at the beginning of the file unless you have a reason to do otherwise.
- The variable `board` is visible in the scope where `random_row` and `random_col` are defined, so you don't need to pass it as a parameter.
- The board size and number of turns are hard-coded twice; in the latter case, you are (probably by mistake) using different numbers. You can make the code more readable by defining constants (variables with upper-case names which can't be changed) for those values and using them later:

  ```
  BOARD_WIDTH = 5
  BOARD_HEIGHT = 5
  MAX_TURNS = 4

  ...

  def random_col():
      return random.randint(0, BOARD_WIDTH - 1)
  ```
- After `break`, you don't need `else` because the loop is left anyway.
- You don't need the parentheses with `elif`.